# how to overwrite initWithRootViewController

Tags: cocoa-touch

How can I overwrite the initWithRootViewController  method in a UINavigationController?

The only methods generated by xcode for me where methods suchs as loadFromNibName and loadView. These methods don't get called and I need to add an NSNotification to the navigationcontroller at startup.

I know it looks a little like the following but I don't know what put in the body of the method

```
- (id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController

{
 // what goes here?
}
```

**EDIT**
I guess the question really is "how do you customize a UIViewCOntroller during initialization"

**Edit 2**

My Navigation Controller header

```
@interface AccountViewNavigationController : UINavigationController {

}
@end
```

Instantiating my UINavigationController Like so will result in no startup methods hitting break point

```
accountViewNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:accountView];
```

Where as if I instantiate like so loadView does get called.... but it gets called numerous times

```
accountViewNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

[accountViewNavController initWithRootViewController:accountView NO];
```

I'm highly confused by this stage.

Comment: Why do you want to override it? If you are using an xib, you can simply change the RootViewController class to another UIViewController subclass

Comment: I want to add the following .. [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveMyEvent:) name:@"MyEvent" object:nil];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the same basic structure you use for overriding any other init method:

```
- (id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    if ((self = [super initWithRootViewController:rootViewController])) {
        // Your modifications go here
    }
    return self;
}
```

Do note that Apple claims UINavigationController is "not intended for subclassing", but they don't absolutely forbid it. I guess that means "don't try to change how the class works by messing with the internal message flow".

Comment: hmmm... I stuck a break point in there and it still doesnt seem to be entering the function?

Comment: @dubbeat: Are you sure you're using your own subclass and not the stock UINavigationController? Are you using IB to create it, in which case you need to use `awakeFromNib` or possibly `initWithCoder:`? Or can you do your code in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear:`, or the like instead?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's "stock". I am not using IB. Doing it in code , viewDidLoad only gets called if I instantiated like so . accountViewNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];. The viewDidload gets called multiple times also which is odd to me?

Comment: @dubbeat: Look what you're doing in `accountViewNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init]`. You're allocating an instance of the stock UINavigationController, not your subclass. So of course your subclass version isn't being called. `viewDidLoad` can be called multiple times (with a `viewDidUnload` in between each) if memory pressure causes non-visible view controllers to release their views.